# Styles not applied in first load using Next.js & Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm using the `Tabs`, `Tab` and `TabPanel` from Material-UI as described on https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/. I'm using it in combination with Next.js.

This is the code I have so far (I removed the GraphQL/Apollo calls, the Next routing and the content to simplify a little bit):
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-6mq4g?file=/demo.js

On Codesandbox, it renders correctly. However, on local, in Chrome, I have the following:

[image]

And this is the inspector:

[image]

If I click on Alice, then Bob again, now everything looks clean:

[image]

And the inspector looks correct (padding is applied accordingly to the `<Box p={3}>`):

[image]

I do not understand why the style is not applied at the first time, on the first load.

Any advices?

Thank you!

Benjamin

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This might be due to SSR (Server Side Rendering) support in Next.js, as material-ui uses JSS for styling, so the styles get loaded in browser after JS is loaded which is not desirable behavior. We need to compute the styles before-hand and inject those styles in the page when doing SSR.
You can read the [guide](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#next-js) on official docs of Material-ui to achieve the correct behavior.